# Asp.Net MVC login form not working on chrome and firefox

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, firefox

I have a login form in MVC which is working on IE but when I am using Chrome and Firefox and I click on Log In (after entering appropriate credentials), the page gets refreshed and and it lands on to the same login page. The validations are working fine though.

```
      @using (Html.BeginForm("LogonStepOne", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new   { @class = "registration-form" }))
        {

            <div class="form-field inputFieldLogin top">
                <label for="AccountNumber">
                Account Number
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AccountNumber, new { pattern = "[0-9]*", title="Please provide account number",maxlength=maxAccountLength,autocomplete = "off" })
            </div>

            <div class="form-field inputFieldLogin bottom">
                <label for="PINCode">
                Password
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.PINCode, new { pattern = "[0-9]*", title = "Please provide your Password",maxlength=@maxPasswordLength,autocomplete = "off" })
            </div>

            <div class="form-field">
                <input type="submit" class="btnShadow" value="Sign In" />
            </div>  

            <div class="validation">
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.AccountNumber)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PINCode)
                @Html.ValidationMessage(ViewModelErrorCodes.UserLogon.USER_IDENTIFICATION_ERROR)
            </div>
        }
```

any hint??

Comment: Could you set a break point inside LogonStepOne, and make sure the break point hit? In addition, use fiddler and see the request.

Comment: i wont be able to debug the application as this issue is occurring on the server application, it is working fine on my local environment.

Comment: What do you see in fiddler? Do you see any script error in the browser? Can you access Production Database from your local machine and replicate the issue on local machine?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? Started yesterday and has been messing my brain.

Comment: For others still facing the issue - restart your chrome browser.